# Nested single/double quotes in Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had thought that single/double quotes were interchangeable in Javascript. So in a jQuery function, could anyone explain why:

```
$('input:radio[name='+foo+'][value='+bar+']').attr('checked', true);
```

works, but

```
$('input:radio[name="+foo+"][value="+bar+"]').attr('checked', true);
```

doesn't? (If `foo` and `bar` are both strings.)

Does nesting double in single/single in double quotes not work?

Comment: StackOverflow's syntax highlighter gives a pretty good clue :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use one quote type inside another, in most modern JavaScript engines, it will treat the inner, alternate-type quotes as quote characters rather than string delimiters.

Comment: "Most [..] engines" haven't got much to do with it: that's how the language is defined!

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal - I agree, the language definition ultimately decides, but there are some old implementations of JavaScript that do not follow the language spec.

Comment: @cdeszaq: Even in this trivial regard? Wow, they _really_ suck!

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal - Yeah, back in the early days when Netscape and IE were just bringing their JavaScript capabilities on line, there were huge disparities in the JavaScript engines.

Comment: @cdeszaq *"in most modern"* should be *"in all modern"*

Comment: @Šime Vidas - I want with _most_ because I don't know all of them :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I searched everywhere for a explanation but surprisingly found nothing, to what I had assumed is a fairly common question!

Answer (score 2):

you cannot nest variable in jQuery, i know you can do that in `php` but not jQuery, just use your 1st option of:

```
$('input:radio[name='+foo+'][value='+bar+']').attr('checked', true);
```

or do this (i changed your second option a bit):

```
$('input:radio[name="'+foo+'"][value="'+bar+'"]').attr('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 2):

It works, but they need to match.  Your opening quote is single, then you're attempting to close it with a double.  This doesn't work.

```
//\/SINGLE          \/DOUBLE
$('input:radio[name="+foo+"][value="+bar+"]').attr('checked', true);
```

The effect of this is that javascript doesn't know that you're trying to terminate the string literal and append the variable value.  It assumes that you are still in the string literal and want the `"` character as part of it.  As long as the quotes match there's no difference between this:

```
var foo = "hello " + world;
```

and

```
var foo = 'hello ' + world;
```

Answer (score 2):

"Interchangeable" does not mean "arbitrary".

It's your choice whether to delimit a string literal with a set of single or of double quotes, but the start and end delimiters for a single string literal must still, of course, be the same.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to put quotes around foo.

```
$('input:radio[name=food]')
```

will work on it's own.

Answer (score 0):

```
'input:radio[name="+foo+"][value="+bar+"]'
```

doesn't work because it's one (single) large string. You are not injecting the `foo` and `bar` variables.

You have to write it like so:

```
'input:radio[name="' + foo + '"][value="' + bar + '"]'
```

---

A simplified example:

`'Value: " + foo + "'` (BAD)

`'Value: "' + foo + '"'` (GOOD)